# Extract values from one row string for foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I extracted two inputed usernames from a text string with @ mention tag.

Now I want to put them in foreach loop so I can use my doctrine instance to search for their user name.

My code:

```
function find(TextEntity $text)
{
    preg_match_all('/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $text->getText(), $usernames);

    $extractedText = implode('", "', $usernames[1]);
}
```

The result I get:

> **"john", "jane"**

I can't find a way to extract them so I can use one by one in foreach loop.

So my try is: (**update:** *working solution*)

```
$usernames = $usernames[1];

$query = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
        ->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('m')
        ->where('m.email IN (:emails)')
        ->setParameter('emails', $usernames)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: `$usernames[1]` is already an array, iterate over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `usernames[1]` is already **an array** you can iterate over it:

```
preg_match_all('/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $text->getText(), $usernames);

$usernames = $usernames[1];
```

And as doctrine supports `where in ()` clause in `findBy` you can use this array without `foreach`:

```
$findUsers = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findBy([
    'username' => $usernames
]);

print_r(findUsers);
```

You can modify this code as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer, and it's working!. @u_mulder